# Crash with 2D C-style arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

A common problem with 2D C-style arrays. This program compiles, but crashes when the `Print()` function is called:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static const int sx = 5, sy = 3;
static double M[sy][sx] = { { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 },
                            { 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 },
                            { 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2 } };

void Print(double **M, int j, int i)
{
    cerr << M[j][i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cerr << M[2][3] << endl;             // Prints 3.2
    Print((double**)&M[0][0], 2, 3);     // Crash
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Is it possible to make it work without changing `Print()`'s signature?

The array is not dynamic.

Comment: You're treating a single pointer as a double pointer. Unfortunately, the signature is plain wrong. The array does not contain pointers. The array itself can decay to a pointer to the first inner array, but again, those are arrays, not pointers.

Comment: A `double[M][N]` is **not** a `double**`. C-style casting it isn't going to change that.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and you can't cast a pointer to a `double` into a pointer to a pointer to a `double` and expect sane things to happen. And, by the way, arrays are not pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
static double M[sy][sx] = { { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 },
                            { 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 },
                            { 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2 } };
```

is nothing remotely like a `double**`, and casting it or anything within it to such a type is incorrect. If you're using a fixed arrays of arrays (call it a 2D array if you want), a compliant print function can be crafted using a template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static const int sx = 5, sy = 3;
static double M[sy][sx] = { { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 },
                            { 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 },
                            { 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2 } };


template<int M>
void Print( double(*ar)[M] , int j, int i )
{
    std::cout << ar[j][i] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Print(M, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Pietro Please note how stride of the array ([M]) needs to be made known to `Print`

Comment: Another option would be `template<size_t X, size_t Y> void Print( double(&ar)[Y][X],`  , then the function could do bounds-checking.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to make the `Print` function work, but you need to change the way you allocate the array. Specifically you need a vector of pointers to the first element of each row, and pass that as the argument.

Here is how you might do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

static const int sx = 5, sy = 3;
static double M[sy][sx] = { { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 },
                            { 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 },
                            { 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2 } };

double **twoD(int nr, int nc) {
// function that allocates a 2D matrix and returns the result
// as a vector of pointers to the first element of each row
  double **p;
  int ii;
  p = (double**)malloc(nr * sizeof(double*));
  p[0] = (double*)malloc(nr * nc * sizeof(double));
  for(ii=1; ii<nr; ii++) {
    p[ii] = p[0] + ii * nc;
  }
  return p;
}

void free2d(double **p) {
  free(p[0]);
  free(p);
}

void Print(double **M, int j, int i)
{
    cerr << M[j][i] << " ";
}

int main()
{
    double **P;
    P = twoD(sy, sx);
    memcpy(P[0], M, sx * sy * sizeof(double));
    cerr << M[2][3] << endl;             // Prints 3.2
    int ii,jj;
    for(ii=0; ii<sy; ii++) {
      for(jj=0; jj<sx; jj++) {
        Print(P, ii, jj);
      }
      cerr << endl;
    }
    free2d(P);
}
```

As you can see - it doesn't change the signature of the `Print()` function, yet allows you to use it without crashing.

I'm not saying I recommend this as the best approach to take - but it answers the question literally. Note I took out the `endl` from `Print` just so that I could convince myself that this would print out the entire array correctly.

This is adapted from `nrutil.c` from "Numerical Recipes in C" (see for example source code [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~gk/class/6964/1/src/nrutil.c) - this is how that book creates variable length 2D arrays (actually they go one step further and allow you to use base 1 offsets - which I find horrific but makes the code "look like" FORTRAN which was the original language of scientific computing).

Comment: *I can't write that bug-free on my phone* - Not with that attitude.

Comment: @chris - creating code that is well formatted and that compiles without errors is something I cannot do reliably on my cell phone - tiny screen, proportional font, .... I have found that posting poorly formatted or buggy code is not appreciated on this site, and thus chose to give the outline of the answer first, then go back and demonstrate my answer with a simple example that compiles without warnings (typos). "That attitude", in my case, is one that recognizes that I make mistakes. I am sorry that you appear to think it means I am lazy or not careful.

Comment: @Floris, Unless this doubles back on me, you might be misunderstanding. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=not%20with%20that%20attitude Not the best use of it I've seen, but eh, what can you do...

Comment: @chris - yes maybe I misunderstood the colloquialism. I will take it as an attempt at humor and let it go. Do you like the updated answer better, at least?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays and pointers are different types. An array is implicitly converted (decays) into a pointer to its first element in some situations like in this case when the array is passed to the `print function`.

The following statement

```
static double M[sy][sx] = { { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 },
                            { 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 },
                            { 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2 } };
```

defines `M` to be an array of `sy`, i.e., `3` elements where each element is of type `double[5]`, i.e., an array of `5` doubles. Therefore, in the `print` function call

```
Print((double**)&M[0][0], 2, 3);
```

`&M[0][0]` evaluates to the address of `M[0][0]` which is of type `(double *)`. **Casting this value to type `(double **)` is wrong because the value at this address is a `double`, not a pointer to a `double`.**

Now, in the `print` function, `M[i][j]` is evaluated to `*(*(M + i) + j)`. Here, the variable `M` (local to the `print` function) is the address of `M[0][0]`. Therefore, `*(M + i)` evaluates to `M[0][i]` which is a `double`. Next, `j` is added to this value and assuming this value to be a valid memory address, the value at that address is fetched. This is plain wrong and invokes undefined behaviour.

You need to change the signature of `print` function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static const int sx = 5, sy = 3;
static double M[sy][sx] = { { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 },
                            { 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1 },
                            { 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2 } };

void Print(double *M, int j, int i)
{
    cerr << M[j*sx + i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cerr << M[2][3] << endl;             // Prints 3.2
    Print(&M[0][0], 2, 3);    
}
```

Comment: I *think* you mean to have that be `M[j*sx + i]` in the Print function if you're planning on keeping the `double*` param. As-written, it won't compile with `M[j][i]`

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, you are right. I had missed that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> The array is not dynamic
>
> Is it possible to make it work without changing Print()'s signature?

Nope, it's not possible to achieve both requirements. Unless it's ok for you to copy that 2D array to another which *is* dynamic.

A 2D array of doubles is not an array of pointers to the rows. Multidimensional arrays are flat as far as memory is concerned. The type of `M[0][0]` is `double` and therefore the type of `&M[0][0]` is `*double`.

See this [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) on using arrays. Pay attention to the chapter "Multidimensional arrays".

What you probably meant to do could be done like this:

```
void Print(double *M, int j, int i, int width) {
    cerr << M[i + width * j] << endl;
}

Print(&M[0][0], 2, 3, sx);
```

Note: As chris commented, this is not technically allowed. [Another reference](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc2.html).

It's possible to do your function and be technically correct, but that requires the function to be particular to the width of the array. Since you use C++, it's not a problem because you can use a template:

```
template<size_t X>
void Print(double M[X], int i) {
    cerr << M[i] << endl;
}

 Print<sx>(M[2], 3);
```

A side note: I don't believe that this one-liner is worthy of being a function. In my opinion it reduces readability and doesn't improve reusability.

Comment: I believe this is technically undefined behaviour because of going out of bounds of the inner five-element array, but I have no doubts that in practicality, it will work regardless.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else already pointed out `&M[0][0]` is a `double *` because you are just retrieving the address of the element `M[0][0]`. If you cast it as a `double **` and then try to stride in memory pretending it really is a `double **` you are basically looking for troubles.
What I guess you are trying to do can be safely achieved by explicitly doing a two-layer allocation, i.e. something like:

```
double ** M = new double*[sy];

for (int iy=0; iy<sy; iy++) {
    M[iy] = new double[sx];
}
```

then (after initialization) `Print(M, 2, 3);` will work fine. I'm afraid you'll have to give up on the array-style initialization with the curly-bracket notation if you do it this way and look for some way around that. (NOTE: my suggestion above is far from efficient for large arrays, as the various 1D chunks of the 2D array are not guaranteed to be allocated contiguously. In general, if size and performance are issues you should consider representing 2D arrays as 1D arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `&M[0][0]` is NOT a `double **`, it is only a pointer to a double (`double *`).
You need to change the function prototype to 
`typedef double my_array_type [3][5]; 
void Print (my_array_type *M, int j, int i)`

Comment: Just changing the signature to that won't help. The function expects some kind of 2D array in the body.